# modifying elements of array in python

Tags: python, algorithm, iteration

I was trying to implement a (naive)`quick_find_union` as follows

```
class QF(object):
    def __init__(self,N):
        self.id=[x for x in range(N)]
    def connected(self,p,q):
        assert type(p)==int
        assert type(q)==int
        return self.id[p]==self.id[q]

    def union(self,p,q):
        assert type(p)==int
        assert type(q)==int
        for x in self.id:
            pid=self.id[p]
            qid=self.id[q]
            if x==pid:
                x=qid
#        for i in range(len(self.id)):
#            pid=self.id[p]
#            qid=self.id[q]
#            if self.id[i]==pid:
#                self.id[i]=qid

    def show_array(self):
        print self.id

if __name__=='__main__':
    qf=QF(10)
    qf.show_array()
    print qf.connected(1,4)
    qf.union(1,4)
    qf.show_array()
    print qf.connected(1,4)
```

This returns

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
False
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
False
```

but when I use only the commented out portion in method union
,it works as expected

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
False
[0, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
True
```

Why is this happening? Has it got something to do with trying to modify the elements of array while iterating? I am not very clear about this..Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x=qid` just rebind the name `x` to the object which the name `qid` refer to. It doesn't modify the element in `self.id` list.

use `enumerate()` to get the both the index and value, and update the `self.id` list by using the index:

```
for i, x in enumerate(self.id):
    pid=self.id[p]
    qid=self.id[q]
    if x==pid:
        self.id[i]=qid
```